# $x^2$ congruent to $1 \pmod {p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

This is probably a really trivial question but I just cannot see the answer...

Suppose $p$ is prime.
Then $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$  has only solutions $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

How do I prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $p$ is prime then the ring $(\Bbb Z_p,+,\times)$ is a finite field and then it's an integral domain. So in $\Bbb Z_p$ we have:
$$x^2=1\iff (x-1)(x+1)=0\implies \big((x-1)=0\big)\vee\big((x+1)=0\big)\iff x=\pm1$$

Answer (score 7):

Basically if $x$ is its own inverse modulo $p$, then $x^2 \equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ p)$. So $p\, |\, (x+1)(x-1)$. Further $p$ is prime so either $x \equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ p)$ or $x \equiv -1\ (\textrm{mod}\ p)$.

If on the other hand, $x \equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ p)$ or $x \equiv -1\ (\textrm{mod}\ p)$, then $x \cdot x \equiv (\pm1)\cdot (\pm1)\ (\textrm{mod}\ p)$, i.e., $x^2 \equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ p)$. $x$ is its own inverse modulo $p$.

Comment: [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma).

Comment: Essentially no [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor).

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly clear that $x \equiv \pm 1$ are solutions.

On the other hand: The equation $x^2 -1 \equiv 0$ cannot have more than 2 solutions because of the degree of this polynomial.

Comment: But if p is not a prime and e.g. 8, the argument doesnt work as 1 , 3, 5, and 7 are solutions.

Comment: Right but you asked about $p$ prime i.e. those congruences are equalities in $\mathbb Z/ p \mathbb Z = \mathbb F _p$.